# not able to connect usb flash drive with android device after using OTG cable

Tags: android, connection

As i had an android device(moto e) and want to connect it with usb.

I tried it by using OTG cable but it didn't detect. Firstly i thought there might be problem in cable but after using another the same problem cont.

Can any one guide me how to use it as i am doing this process 1st time.

Comment: Stock android does not support usb storage devices without an application to do so.  Some devices may not have functional host mode at all.

Answer (score 0):

I am using an OTG cable to connect a midi keyboard to my Android device, my experience is that lots of cables that are sold as OTG cables are simple no OTG cables. They have the correct connectors, but an OTG cable requires [pin 4 and 5 need to be connected with each other](http://www.googlenexusforum.com/forum/attachments/nexus-7-discussions/1491d1346078197-built-my-own-otg-cable-today-under-hour-difference_circuit_271738111300.jpg)  otherwise your Android device will be an USB client instead of a host.  I had to purchase 3 OTG cables before I found one that worked. Also note that some Android devices do support OTG, but they don't offer power to the OTG device.